# React Native Navigator stack screen header spacing different on different screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack with five screens in it, all with the same navigation.setOptions in a useEffect that is setting the right header with a touchable icon to navigate else where. On the first screen the icon is slightly in a different spot. I think its somehow related to being the first screen as all the screens have the same code and its only off in the first screen.

Calling AuthedTabScreen

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
  <SafeAreaProvider>
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      {user == null ? (
        <>
          <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <RootStack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <RootStack.Screen name="Authed" component={AuthedTabScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      )}
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  </SafeAreaProvider>
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Make the bottom tab navigator and call BorrowerDashboardStack

```
function AuthedTabScreen() {
return (
  <>
    <AuthedTab.Navigator screenOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.blue }}>
      <AuthedTab.Screen
        name="DashboardTab"
        component={
          isRealtor(user.role)
            ? RealtorDashboardStackScreen
            : isApplicant(user.role)
            ? BorrowerDashboardStackScreen
            : LoanTeamDashboardStackScreen
        }
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Dashboard',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icons name="home" size={size} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      {user.role === 'Applicant' && (
        <AuthedTab.Screen
          name="Documents"
          component={DocView}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icons name="document-text" size={size} color={color} />,
          }}
        />
      )}
      <AuthedTab.Screen
        name="Calculator"
        component={Calculator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icons name="calculator" size={size} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <AuthedTab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icons name="settings" size={size} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </AuthedTab.Navigator>
  </>
);
```

}

BorrowerDashboardStack

```
function BorrowerDashboardStackScreen() {
return (
  <BorrowerDashboardStack.Navigator>
    <BorrowerDashboardStack.Screen name="Home" component={BorrowerDashboardScreen} />
    <BorrowerDashboardStack.Screen
      name="Doc Viewer"
      component={PdfViewer}
      options={{
        title: '',
      }}
    />
    <BorrowerDashboardStack.Screen
      name="Intake"
      component={IntakeFormScreen}
      options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params?.name ?? 'Intake' })}
    />
    <BorrowerDashboardStack.Screen name="Contacts" component={BorrowerContacts} />
    <BorrowerDashboardStack.Screen name="Calculator" component={Calculator} />
  </BorrowerDashboardStack.Navigator>
);
```

}

useEffect setting the header on all screens

```
useEffect(() => {
navigation.setOptions({
  headerRight: () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('Contacts');
      }}
    >
      <Icon name="people" size={25} color={colors.dkGrey} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
});
```

The Home Screen Header
[image: The Home Screen Header]

The Document Screen Header
[image: The Document Screen Header]

I have tried switching screens, calling the stack in different ways, changing css. I am trying to make everything looking like the Document Screen Header, changing css gets me close but it not consent.

Comment: use code in text so that other can use them easily .it is little hard for us to look at these images and guess >